# How to Display Data in C# form mysql table?

Tags: c#, mysql, console-application

I am new on C# . I create a C# Console program and insert some data to MySql by following code .

```
string connection = "Server=localhost;Database=user_table;Uid=root;Pwd=";
MySqlConnection dbcon = new MySqlConnection(connection);
MySqlCommand cmd;
dbcon.Open();

cmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERt INTO user_table(user_name,amount)   VALUES(@user_name,@amount)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_name","Niloy");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", "456");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now I want to retrieve this data and display in console application .
like This

Niloy      234

Joy        500

Minal      230

how can i do this ?

Comment: This is your insert code. Did you try anything about display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the opposite of that you have already done for the insertion of data.

```
// You sql command
MySqlCommand selectData;

// Create the sql command
selectData = dbcon.CreateCommand();

// Declare the sript of sql command
selectData.CommandText = "SELECT user_name, amount, FROM user_table";

// Declare a reader, through which we will read the data.
MySqlDataReader rdr = selectData.ExecuteReader();

// Read the data
while(rdr.Read())
{
    string userName = (string)rdr["user_name"];
    string amount = (string)rdr["amount"];

    // Print the data.
    Console.WriteLine(username+" "+amount);
}

rdr.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving your valuable time. When I create MySqlReader rdr = selectData.ExecuteReader(); Object , MySqlReader get Red sign , I think its cant recognize MySqlReader . What whould I do ? @Christos

Comment: I didn't See MySqlReader in suggestion list when i m writing (Drop down menu )

Comment: @Niloy yeah, you are right ! I am sorry. I just updated my post. Please let me know, if that's ok now. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
using (dbcon)
{
dbcon.Open();
cmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Select user_name,amount from   user_table";

 MySqlReader  sqlreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

              while (sqlreader.Read())
              {
                 Console.WriteLine(sqlreader[0].ToString()+ " "+(sqlreader[1].ToString());
              }
              sqlreader.Close();

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving your valuable time. When I create MySqlReader rdr = selectData.ExecuteReader(); Object , MySqlReader get Red sign , I think its cant recognize MySqlReader . What whould I do ? @apomene

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gridview` to display your data, Using the similar way you used to insert data into your Table.

```
string connection = "Server=localhost;Database=user_table;Uid=root;Pwd=";
MySqlConnection dbcon = new MySqlConnection(connection);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

MySqlCommand cmd;
dbcon.Open();

cmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from user_table";
adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adapter.Fill(dt);
Gridview1.DataSource=dt;
Gridview1.DataBind();
```